# Next.js, redirect to 404 Not Found Page inside getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am looking for a best practice in a server-side rendered page on handling an HTTP 404 if the requested page does not have an underlying server-side resource.

For example, let's assume the page requested is `http://localhost:3000/places/5`. In my SSG implementation:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const placeId = context.params.placeId;
  const places = await getPlace(placeId);
  
  if (!places.length) { /* is there anything here I can do to facilitate a 404? this place does not exist in the db */ }

  return {
    props: {
      places[0],
    },
  };
}
```

This should be self-explanatory, but if the requested id, in this case, `5` is not a place that's in my DB, how do I handle this as an HTTP 404?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can do that by returning an object like in the below code, with `notFound: true`. And here is a quote from the official [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#notfound):

> The `notFound` boolean allows the page to return a `404` status and `404` Page.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const placeId = context.params.placeId;
  const places = await getPlace(placeId);

  if (!places.length) { 
   return {
     notFound: true,
   }
  }

  return {
    props: {
      places[0],
    },
  };
}
```